# MongoDB error on mongos: too many positional options

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to run a batch script which is suppose to be my first ever sharding on mongodb. It shows following error in this line:

```
D:\mongodb-win32-x86_64-2.2.3\bin>mongos --configdb localhost:26050, localhost:26051, localhost:26052  --logappend --logpath log.mongos0

error command line: too many positional options
use --help for help
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "too many positional operators" error means you have a mismatch in the number of command line parameters and values provided.

Specifically, the spaces between names of config servers are being interpreted as different (unknown) parameters.

Corrected command line:

```
mongos --configdb localhost:26050,localhost:26051,localhost:26052 --logappend --logpath log.mongos0
```