# how to run mongoexport csv with a query

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to export a mongodb query to csv file. here's what I have:

```
mongoexport --db db_name --collection agents --query ‘{ $and: [ {clients_count: {$gt:2}}, {vendors_count:{$gt:10}} ] }’ --csv --fieldFile userFields.txt --out outputFilePathAndName.csv
```

I got the following error:

```
Error parsing command line: too many positional options
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Those curly quotes make me wonder.

Comment: Try changing your quotes. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25921183/mongoexport-too-many-positional-options

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does "too many positional options" mean when doing a mongoexport?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7521163/what-does-too-many-positional-options-mean-when-doing-a-mongoexport)

Comment: @JuanCarlosFarah thanks, but I'm still not getting it. I only have one set of single quotes.  Should each argument also be in quotes?  I'm on a Mac if that makes a difference.

Comment: Have you tried using straight double quotes? `--query "{ ... }"`?

Comment: @JuanCarlosFarah  yup. didn't work.

Comment: I removed the paces in the query per this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15185238/mongodb-error-on-mongos-too-many-positional-options, but now have another error: `assertion: 16619 code FailedToParse: FailedToParse: Expecting '}' or ',': offset:56 of:{$and:[{clients_count:{$gt:2}},{vendors_count:{$gt:10}}]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

got it.  correct query:

```
mongoexport --db db_name --collection collectionName --query '{$and:[{clients_count:{$gt:2}},{vendors_count:{$gt:10}}]}' --csv --fieldFile userFields.txt --out filepat/fileName.csv
```

the key is to use single quotes `'` and leave no spaces in the query.

**EDIT**

having issue with the fields, but seems to be grabbing the correct documents.